# Google Actions Error using Webhook Fulfillment : Error Querying Agent Endpoint

Tags: actions-on-google

I am following the steps to build a push notifications engagement on Google Assistant using the steps mentioned here : https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/notifications

On deploying the action, the webhook is failing with the following errors :

```
code: 3
message: "Unsuccessful webhook call due to client issue: Error querying agent endpoint. State: URL_UNREACHABLE, reason: UNREACHABLE_5xx."
```

and

```
webhookResponse: {
responseJson: "{"error":"Cannot read property 'permissionStatus' of undefined"}"
}
```

Anyone facing similar issues? I understand that the document might not be updated and additional steps are required